# Regex to match PowerShell drive path

Tags: regex, powershell

PowerShell's `New-PsDrive` Cmdlet allows for drives to be created with more-flexible names like `HKLM`.

I'd like to match these drive\path\file patterns in the `NavigationCmdletProvider` that I'm building:

```
csb:
csb:\
csb:\foo\bar
csb:\foo\bar\
csb:\foo\bar bar\test.txt
```

but not these

```
csb:\\
csb:\\\
```

`([a-zA-Z]+:)?(\\[a-zA-Z0-9_.-: :]+)*\\?` matches everything that I want, but still includes the two that I don't.  I can't seem to get it to match 0 or 1 `\` at the end of the string.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

All you should need to do is tie your regular expression to the beginning and end of the line using a `^` and a `$` respectively:

```
^([a-zA-Z]+:)?(\\[a-zA-Z0-9_.-: :]+)*\\?$
```

This is necessary almost any time you are trying to count a specific number of character in a regex.